# Is it possible to call a textbox in the middle of quotation C# VB

Tags: c#

i want to make a email to sms program using c#. In the body of the text i would like to call a textbox where the value of what user put there will be replace in a line there..

below is my coding :

```
    public string FromAddress = "cmdsa.system@gmail.com";

    public string Password = "XXXXXXXXXX";

    public string To = "sms@isms.com.my";

    public string Subject = "isms";

    public string Body =
    "STARTISMS
    username:password:1
    6017xxxxxxx, <--  here is where i want to call a textbox where it will 
                      be replace with the value entered in the box at the
                      interface.
    testing 1234567890
    ENDISMS";

    public string Smtp = "smtp.gmail.com";

    public int Port = 587;
```

Please tell me a right way to do this.. including the right way on how to write a multiple text of the below inside the body part

```
"STARTISMS
 username:password:1
 6017xxxxxxx, <--  here is where i want to call a textbox where it will be  
                   replace with the value entered in the box at the 
                   interface.
 testing 1234567890
 ENDISMS";
```

Comment: You cannot do this inside a field declaration. This is basic knowledge, you should read a good book or tutorial that will expain this in detail.

Answer (score 0):

Not clear! Why you put inputs in property directly? If they are alwasy static , for making body property, you can on click of send button make it.

```
body = "S.T" + textBox1.Text;
```

if else, explain your problem clearly.

Comment: ohh sorry for not stating the above code is in my class where at the button or textbox i bind data to the property. for an example :
TextBox Text="{Binding Model.Body}" 
Body is indicating the property of Body in the question i ask.. i make this using wpf..

body = "S.T" + textBox1.Text;
i want to put a text box like this
body = "S.T +Texbox1.Text any other words"
can it be done?